# How do I reference to a class using a string in python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to make a text-based game that's kinda like pokemon. It's been going pretty well but I've run into an issue when accessing a move using a string input from the user (the moves are classes). There are going to be a lot of moves that will have been created, but I don't actually know if that'll affect how this accessing is done. Whenever I run my code or the similar code below I get this error.

```
what is a classname you want? myClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    Main()
  File "main.py", line 10, in Main
    print(userClass.name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is the code that is a simplified version of what I've been using.

```
def Main():
    class X():
        name=""

    myClass=X()
    myClass.name="this"

    userClass=str(input('what is a classname you want?'))
    print(userClass.name)
Main()
```

UPDATE:
I changed what I used based on edits, but I'm still getting an error. Here's the code:

```
def Main():
    class X():
        name=""

    myClass=X()
    myClass.name="this"

    userClass = globals()[str(input('What is a class name you want?'))]
    print(userClass.name)
Main()
```

And here's the error I got:

```
What is a class name you want? myClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 10, in <module>
  File "python", line 8, in Main
KeyError: 'myClass'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually, and I did it by using dictionaries. Here is the code behind it.

```
def Main():
    class aClass():
        name=""
    myClass=aClass()
    myClass.name="this"

    classes={}
    classes["myClass"]=myClass

    userClass=str(input('class name'))
    print(classes[userClass].name)

Main()
```

Comment: I would move the mapping out so that 1) it isn't recreated each time the function is run, and 2) it can be added to by code in other modules. Those may not matter in this toy code, but they can make a huge difference in real projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()`. Previously, I suggested using `globals()`. But, `myClass` isn't in global scope, so `globals()` won't work. The code will look something like:

```
userClass = locals()[str(input('What is ...'))]
print(userClass.name)
```

Though, I must say, I believe that their is a better way to solve your problem. But, that's already out of the scope of this question.

---

#### Here's my first answer before his clarifications

`userClass` is not a user-defined class instance. In your case, it's not an instance of class `X`. Rather, it is declared as  a string. And strings don't have a `name` attribute. That is what's causing your error.

What you want to do is make `userClass` an instance of class `X`, basing from your code.

```
userClass = X()
```

To set the `userClass`'s `name` attribute with some user input, you can just simply do:

```
userClass.name = str(input('what is a classname you want?'))
print(userClass.name)
```

---

#### Side notes

- `AttributeError`s occur when you are accessing a non-existent attribute in an object.
- In Python, it's recommended that you use snake case instead of camel case. I.e. `userName` would be `user_name`. Function names are to start with lower cases.
- The variable `name` inside class `X` is a static variable. Meaning, if you have multiple instances of `X` and you give `name` in an instance of `X` somewhere a new value, all the other instances will have the new value of `name` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained poorly. What I want to be able to do is type in myClass for the input and then be able to access myClass's values if I plug the variable userClass in somewhere, however I get the error that myClass doesn't have a name attribute. Thanks for the explanation on common practice in python though!

Comment: @BigBoiBif, if I am getting this right, you want `userClass` to represent/be a "pointer" for `myClass`. Correct? From your question, the player moves by typing the move they want and that move is a class instance?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I want it to do

Comment: I used your edits but I still got an error, and am not quite sure why...

Comment: What is a class name you want? myClass
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "python", line 10, in <module>
      File "python", line 8, in Main
    KeyError: 'myClass'